# preventLazyLoading() in app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php doesn't work

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I have the following code, but it does not throw exception even though I am in local-development environment

```
$user = User::findOrFail(34);
$user->videos;
```

app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php

```
...
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
...

public function boot()
{
  Model::preventLazyLoading(true);
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#preventing-lazy-loading

> After preventing lazy loading, Eloquent will throw a
> Illuminate\Database\LazyLoadingViolationException exception when your
> application attempts to lazy load any Eloquent relationship.

**why doesn't it work?**

Answer (score 1):

You must change `User` model to `Model` class

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Model::preventLazyLoading(! $this->app->isProduction());
}
```

To avoid messy error message on production site `!$this->app->isProduction()`.

To prevent `preventLazyLoading`, `preventSilentlyDiscardingAttributes` and `preventAccessingMissingAttributes` just include one line of this code `Model::shouldBeStrict(! $this->app->isProduction())`

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Model::shouldBeStrict(! $this->app->isProduction());
}
```

Comment: hi @Sophy I just put `Model` instead of the `User` model in question, but it still does not work.